# Why does this javascript height calculation break when the page is refreshed, but not when it's first loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm setting the height of a div based on a calculation from the height of a parent div, but it screws up when I refresh the page.

Here's a simplified version of the javascript:

```
$(function() {
  var containerHeight = $('#container').height();
  if ($('#toolbar').length) {
    $('#content').css({'height' : containerHeight - 120});
  } else {
    $('#content').css({'height' : containerHeight});
  };
});
```

Here's a rough idea of the html:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 90%;">
  <div id="content" style="overflow-x:scroll;">stuff here</div>
  <div id="toolbar">stuff here</div><!-- toolbar height is 120px and only rendered on some pages -->
</div>
```

On the first page load, everything works fine. All the content is contained in the content div with a scroll. However if I refresh the page the content div will not scroll all the way to the bottom of its actual content. I've worked with it in Chrome and Safari. Am I missing something really simple?

Comment: When does it fail? toolbar.length return true improperly, false improperly or either way? Also, code is actually executing in all cases, correct?

Comment: You have an unexpected `;` when closing `else` statement. -> `};`

Comment: I'm using the .length() property simply to see if the toobar is there. Should I use something else?

Comment: @Preacher I would consider troubleshooting page load vs document load issues.  I know I had height issues, particularly in Webkit browsers (ie. Safari/Chrome), due to how they handle this.  Though, I would expect it to happen on both refresh and first load.   This is usually related to images. See this: http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: using **.length** probably checks if the property of method is available (always will). Try something like **length > 0**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how or why, but a rework of the html & javascript got it working. Here's the javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var contentHeight = $('#content').height();
  if ($('#new_comment').length) {
    $('#viewport').css({'height' : contentHeight - 120});
  } else {
    $('#viewport').css({'height' : contentHeight});
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its something with caching and the order things are loaded in the page?  Where are you calling the function?   Try calling it from within $(document).ready(function(){...}) or something along those lines